# [PHP]Insert TextArea elements into array and print it

Tags: php, html, listbox

I am fairly new in PHP. I am developing a small tool that take elements from a list box (which has elements loaded from a textfile) then merges it with other strings hand inserted inside a text area.

More explanation :
There is a list box that load strings from a text file
Then I've a **text area** where the user inputs text (string)
On press of a button, I want the application to merge each item in the list box with each item in the text area, for example:

```
[LISTBOX]
ITALY
USA
GERMANY

[TEXTAREA]
GREAT
GOOD
VERY GOOD

[PRINTED RESULT ON BUTTON PRESS]
ITALY GREAT
ITALY GOOD
ITALY VERY GOOD
USA GREAT
USA GOOD
USA VERY GOOD
GERMANY GREAT
GERMANY GOOD
GERMANY VERY GOOD
```

> My code
>   http://sharetext.org/RaB3

```
<html>
<head><title>TOOL</title></head>
<body>
<div align="center">
<img src="../img/logo.png" width="30%" height="16%">
</div>
<br><br>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<?php
$file_handle = fopen("myfile.txt", "rb");
$i=0;
while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
$line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
$parts = explode(';', $line_of_text);
$citta[$i]=array($parts[0]);
$i=$i+1;
}
fclose($file_handle);
?>
<div name="lista" align="left">
<select name="listacitta" multiple="multiple">')
<?for ($cit = 0; $cit <= $i-2; ++$cit)
{
        echo('<option>' . $citta[$cit][0] .'</option>');
    } ?>
</select>
</div></td>    
<td>
<textarea name="keywords" width="500" height="400" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea>
<?
for ($eco = 0; $eco <= $i-2; ++$eco)
{
//echo('ciao ' . $citta[$eco][0] . '<br>');
}
?>
</td>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Then do you need it using ajax so result appear in the same page or when user click button it shows a blank page with results , also you didn't need to show up list in this view you can process it directly

Comment: Oh, thank you so much Damien Joe, you fixed my post and my bad english too, WOW! Thank you :))

Comment: How is this ?
iam the editor of your post , but it appears with an other one name ?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got the question right and I think this is what you need:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>TOOL</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center">
        <img src="../img/logo.png" width="30%" height="16%">
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <form action="#" method="post">
    <table> 
        <tr>
            <td> 
                <?php 
                $file_handle = fopen("myfile.txt", "rb"); 
                while (!feof($file_handle) ) { 
                    $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle); 
                    $parts = explode(';', $line_of_text); 
                } 
                fclose($file_handle); 
                ?> 
                <div name="lista" align="left"> 
                    <select name="listacitta[]" multiple="multiple">
                        <?php 
                        for($cit = 0; $cit<count($parts); $cit++) { 
                          echo('<option value="' . $parts[$cit] . '">' . $parts[$cit] .'</option>'); 
                        };
                        ?> 
                    </select> 
                </div>
            </td> 
            <td> 

            <textarea name="keywords" width="500" height="400" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['keywords']) && !empty($_POST['listacitta'])) {
        $usertext = $_POST['keywords'];
        $userSelect = $_POST['listacitta'];
        $userTparts = explode(';', $usertext);
        for($z=0;$z<count($userSelect);$z++) {
            for($y=0;$y<count($userTparts);$y++){
                echo $userSelect[$z] . " " . $userTparts[$y] . "<br />";
            };
        };
    };  
?>
</body> 
</html>
```

I didn't find the need for the multi-dimensional array `$citta` so I took that out.

Note that this script explodes your user text input by ";". Some refining might be needed for your use.

Happy coding.

Comment: Hi Bogdan thank you so much is what I'm looking for!!! just a question, why now my "myfile.txt" doesen't load anymore in LISTBOX with your code?THANKS SO MUCH :)

Comment: none of the items load? my "myfile.txt" is written on a single line like this: `ITALY; USA; GERMANY` and it works like a charm :S

Comment: None of them! I tryed to replace your code with mine for load items, but when I press SUBMIT it doesen't merge with items in TEXTAREA. I need that all items in myfile.txt will be merged with all items in textarea so if I've in myfile.txt "ITALY;USA;" and in textarea "GOOD;GRET" it have to show: "ITALY GOOD" [NEWLINE] "ITALY GREAT" [NEWLINE] "USA GOOD" [NEWLINE] "USA GREAT". I hope you understand and I'm sorry if my explaination s0x :) thank you so much for your time Bogdan!!!

Comment: for debbuging you can try `echo $line_of_text;` to see if it gets anything from the file. I placed "myfile.txt" in the same folder as the script.

Comment: If I put echo $line_of_text; in the "while" it work, but if I put it out of WHILE then it doesen't work anymore!

Comment: Well then, try and delete the while loop from my function, but leave the content. should get you the same result. also, you could declare the `$parts` array as global as in functions, but I don't think that should be needed here. I have no idea why this does not work for you... I made this script on my computer and it runs perfectly.